# how much of this is auto-generated methods in Rails "User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How much of this is auto-generated methods in Rails "User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)".  That is just wondering how this works, and what would have been the minimum coding the dev would have to do?  That is, what method would they have had to implement in the User model?  or would they need a method named exactly that.  So just wondering if the "find", "create", "from" keywords are Rails specials here.

Taken from here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails provides the dynamic finders `find_by_*`, `find_or_initialize_by_*`, and `find_or_create_by_*` via method_missing for each attribute of your model.

The `self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)` method however isn't at all provided by rails and is simply using the same type of naming conventions for readability.

EDIT:
Apparently it also provides `find_last_by_*` and `find_all_by_*` as well. I've personally never used them though.